# Image in listview

Tags: android, image, listview

so I am trying to get an image into my listview. The xml code is all set up from it I am just not sure about how to get the image in it. The image is coming to the app as a string that I will convert into the image like so:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(shr_image,
            Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0,
            decodedBytes.length);
```

And everything else is set into the listview in:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllSpotsActivity.this, spotsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME, "sdistance","dateof","timeof" }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.distance, R.id.date, R.id.time});
```

and...

```
map.put(TAG_PID, id);
map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
map.put("distance", distance);
map.put("sdistance", dist_display);
map.put("timeAway", timeAway);
map.put("dateof", date);
map.put("timeof", time);
```

How would I go about adding an image to in?

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `SimpleAdapter` anymore once you have to do something memory intensive such as loading bitmaps. SimpleAdapter does not give you the ability to efficiently recycle view data because you have to build the entire map in memory.

You should probably derive a new class from `CursorAdapter` if you are using a content provider or database and derive from `BaseAdapter` if you need to do something more customized.

Comment: How would I go about that? Would everything else be the same as far as map.put goes or...?

Comment: No it is totally different, there is no map. How to use CursorAdapter is well documented here and all over the web. No use discussing it again in these comments.

Answer (score 1):

You should use custom adapter for your ListView that will be much easier. Go through the following which may help you...

[Android: Custom ListView with Image and Text using BaseAdapter](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/)